# Undecorate string from type_info.raw_name

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Let's say I have a string returned by the expression `typeid(int(&(*)())[10]).raw_name()`. In Visual C++, it returns `.P6AAAY09HXZ`. How can I obtain the original type expression, or at least something close to it? I've already tried *UnDecorateSymbolName*, but it returns the input. It appears that this function only works on decorated function names. Is it possible to modify the returned code so the function would accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`boost::core::demangle`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/core/doc/html/core/demangle.html) or [`boost::typeindex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_typeindex_header_reference.html#header.boost.type_index_hpp):

```
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
```

```
using type = int(&(*)())[10];

auto name = typeid(type).name();
std::cout << boost::core::demangle( name ) << '\n';

std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id<type>().pretty_name() << '\n';
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2396ec6c44ef4b2c)

Comment: Certainly interesting, but are you sure it would work for Visual C++ decorated names? According to Boost sources, the function uses "cxxabi.h", and that's probably missing in Visual C++ implementation.